# MethodNotAllowedHttpException on large post data

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a form to compose email and save it to queue.

This form will send post data such as:

- Email addresses (comma separated)
- Email Subject
- Email Message

This form is working perfectly on small amount of data (under 5000 email address)

But, recently my data grow bigger and now its 11,493 email address. Its 267404 character.

Some thing went wrong and throwing

```
**MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:**
```

I have tried to do

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '100000');
ini_set('memory_limit','512M');
ini_set('post_max_size','64M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','32M');
```

and its still error.

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: What is the method?

Comment: @user2182349: POST. Sorry I haven't mention it